# vim match errors out with regular expression (?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$

Tags: vim

Trying to build pluralize function with vim script

I have this regular expression copied from php script to make plural words

```
/(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$/i   \1\2ves
```

However this does not work with vim

```
if "calf" =~ "\\v(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$"
  echo "matched"
end if
```

it errors out `E64: ? follows nothing`

I think I don't fully understand this regular expression, and how can I make it use with vim script?

Answer (score 2):

Vim's regular expression dialect is slightly different from the more common POSIX regexps and Perl-compatible regexps.

The `?:` which is used for grouping without capturing the submatch is expressed in Vim as `\%(...\)` (or `\v%(...)` in *very magic* mode). Therefore, you have to use:

```
if 'calf' =~ '\v%([^f])fe|([lr])f)$'
```

(Note how I've switched to single quotes to avoid escaping the backslash.)

Comment: Thanks, i could not find vim specific expression from google or help. a link would be helpful to learn more about vim regular expression. `single quote to avoid backslash` is a great tip. thanks again